# Зачем нужен шаблон без параметра?

Tags: c++

Есть пример кода. Совершенно не понимаю что это. Можно просто ссылку, где почитать об этом.

```
/* implement hash function so we can put GridLocation into an unordered_set */
template <> struct hash<GridLocation> {
  typedef GridLocation argument_type;
  typedef std::size_t result_type;
  std::size_t operator()(const GridLocation& id) const noexcept {
    return std::hash<int>()(id.x ^ (id.y << 4));
  }
};
```

Фрагмент с [этого](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html) сайта.

Comment: Ищите *специализация шаблонов*. Например - https://habr.com/ru/post/54762/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не "шаблон без параметра". Это специализация шаблона, принимающего не менее одного параметра, для типа `GridLocation`. Это нужно для переопределения поведения шаблона для конкретного типа. Например `has<int>` будет иметь одну реализацию, а `hash<GridLocation>` - другую, `hash<ваш_тип_тут>` - третью.